# Merging a resource from another Assembly in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-5.0, resourcedictionary, pack-uri

I added a Resource Dictionary named ResourceDictionary1 to my silverlight project.

I also added a Silverlight Class Library to my project named OtherAssembly, then in this new assembly I added a new Resource Dictionary named ResourceDictionary2:

[image: Project Structure]

In my original project I'm trying to merge both dictionaries in MainPage.xaml:

```
  <ResourceDictionary>
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary1.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/OtherAssembly;component/MyResourceDictionary2.xaml" />
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

When I run the project the line with OtherAssembly throws an exception, saying that **there's an error assigning the property System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source in that line**:

[image: Error]

But at design time, the designer shows everything in order, it finds all the resources.

I don't know, It seems that the Pack Uri syntax is not well formed.

Anybody knows why I get this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

I needed to add a reference to OtherAssembly, as the error is not detected until run time, it's hard to detect it.